# How can I flush a json response in a controller?

Tags: 8, ajax

Didn't find this when I googled before, posting to maybe save the next person some time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe obvious for people familiar with Symfony, but was new for me; spent way too long trying to find something so simple:

```
$json_response = new JsonResponse($my_key_value_array);
$json_response->send();
$this->function_that_takes_a_long_time();
```